# Rewrite Rule for Domain Aliases on Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a situation where in I have my main domain name as :
`www.example1.com` and I have an alias domain `www.getexample1.com`

Now, if someone hits `www.getexample1.com`, I wish to redirect to `www.example1.com/newpage` ; but `www.example1.com` should not undergo that redirection.

I tried using virtual host for this but it went into a redirect loop. Is there a `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` that can help solve the above issue?

Attempted Virtual Host Code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
    ServerName www.example1.com
    ServerAlias getexample1.com
    Redirect / https://www.example1.com/newpage
    DocumentRoot "var/www/html"
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I wish to only redirect getexample1.com to the redirect address, and not my name server domain. How can that be achieved?

Comment: Please share your attempted configuration. It sounds surprising that you would run into a redirection loop just because of using virtual host. Actually you _should_ use a name based virtual loop for this.

Comment: Updated with the attempted code.

Comment: Those are not two virtual hosts, that is a single host with an Alias. You want to define two separate hosts.

Comment: So I need to declare two virtual hosts with having www.example1.com and the other as www.getexample1.com ?

Comment: Depends a little on what you actually want to do. But in general, when using different host names, you want separate virtual hosts. Why else two host names?

Comment: Some customers use an older domain hence we have two host names. Can I not have just one virtual host with the older domain and redirection rules to do the trick?

Comment: Sure you can, but it adds complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Definately.

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.getexample1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(index.(php|html))?$ http://www.example1.com/newpage [R=302,L]
```

Now, `^www\.getexample1\.com$` could also be `^(www\.)?getexample1\.com$` for matching both, www and no-www domain.

`^/?(index.(php|html))?$` will match `/`, `index.php` and `index.html`, you can play around with this regex to, according to your requirements.

I used a 302 redirection for testing purposes, you can set it as a 301 redirection when you're sure that you have coded the rules you want (to prevent webbroser redirection caching issues).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there some issue with the regex here? My apache log states :  RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^(/?index.(php|html)?$'

Comment: Sorry, i missed one closing parentheses, i updated my rules. Please try again.

Comment: While I think your rules maybe correct - I need to clarify something. We have our old domain registered somewhere, and we are already redirecting www.getexample1.com to www.example1.com - should we simply remove this redirection ? Because currently if I type in getexample1.com, it simply redirects to example1.com and not the newpage as intended

Comment: There is a change that my rules conflic with your old rules. Also remember to remove your browsers cache because it may have stored previous 301 redirections that could have been sent by your server.

Comment: Yes - I did clear my browser cache, testing on icognito. So I am guessing that there is a redirection conflict occurring? There is no rule as such, the domain site is doing the redirection work themselves, we only had to enter the desired location.

Comment: Yes, it seems to me that you old redirection rules catch client's request and inmediately redirects them to **www.example1.com**, regardless the REQUEST_URI. It would mean that my htaccess rules won't even be processed, because the old redirection happened in a previous stage.